# Waiting with setting ItemSource to list from ToListAsync()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone

I am trying to set the ItemSource in the following way:

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("mydb.db");
var query = conn.Table<mytable>();
mylist = await query.ToListAsync();
MyListView.ItemsSource = mylist;
```

But at the moment of setting `ItemsSource` the var `mylist` is not set yet. How do I wait for it to complete?

Comment: *"But at the moment of setting ItemsSource the var mylist is not set yet"* Are you sure? You're asynchronously waiting on it, it should complete before preceding. Have you debugged your code?

Comment: well if I debug after setting the Itemsource I see that mylist is often empty. if I break before setting itemsource and in that wy give it more timeits always set.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `MyListView.ItemsSource = mylist;` and view `mylist` in the debugger, is it empty?

Comment: If I break on that line then mylist is filled and also i see the items in my listview. But without the break mylistview is often empty.